# How can I change toolbar button label text and tooltip in CKeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to change label text and tool tip for buttons in CKedtior , i changed like to have label text for buttons with default values. Can I change default values to user defined values?

Comment: Please post your code with question.

Comment: I got a solution,   i'm doing it this way for now:

for source button label
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() {
    $(".cke_button__source_label").text("View Source");
 });
for other button labels we need to change class of label

Comment: Why not simply edit language files (https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/major/lang) and build your custom editor (https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_build)?

Comment: I'm trying to change them from another application,  so trying to change them from config file

Comment: we can change title(tool tip) for buttons ex:CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() {
$(".cke_button__pastefromword_label").text("From Word");
$('.cke_button__pastefromword').prop('title', 'From Word-title');
  });

Answer (score 0):

In CKEditor source, buttonview.js states this:

```
/**
 * Label of the button view. It is configurable using the {@link #label label attribute}.
 *
 * @readonly
 * @member {module:ui/view~View} #labelView
 */
```

After reading this, I tried the following steps which works just fine:

1. In @ckeditor\ckeditor5-core\src\command.js, add `this.set( 'tooltipTitle', '' );` right below `this.set( 'isEnabled', false );`
2. In your buttons ui script, for instance @ckeditor\ckeditor5-list\src\listui.js, update `buttonView.bind` line to include `'label'` in arguments of `bind` and `'tooltipTitle'` in arguments of `to`. Something like `buttonView.bind( 'isOn', 'isEnabled', 'label' ).to( command, 'value', 'isEnabled', 'tooltipTitle' );`.
3. In the refresh function of the command script, for instance listcommand.js in the same directory with listui.js, update this.label to whatever you want tooltip to be, `this.label = checkConditionsAndGetTooltipLabel();`;